# Variable [x] already defined in method [y] - but different scopes

Tags: java, netbeans, scope

I am not sure why this code is not working. As you can see, variable `x` is clearly present in two places - but they are in two different scopes. In the example below, they are in two different `case` statements and the 2nd one is in a further `if` statement. What gives? Why am I getting this error stating that the variable is "already defined"? Latest compiler and Netbeans. I am used to C++, and this is not an issue. Thanks!

```
package testapp;

public class TestApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int decisionValue1 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        int decisionValue2 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());

        switch (decisionValue1)
        {
            case 1:
                int x = decisionValue1;
                System.out.println(x);
                break;

            case 2:
                if (decisionValue2 == 4)
                {
                    int x = decisionValue2;
                    System.out.println(x);
                }

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }    
}
```

To be specific, the error is:

```
[Source Dir]: error: variable x is already defined in method main(String[])
```

**EDIT:**

Hey guys. Since the initial responses concentrated on the `switch` statement, I made a modified example below. No `switch` statement, but SAME error!

```
public class TestApp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int decisionValue1 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());
        int decisionValue2 = Integer.parseInt(System.console().readLine());

        int x = decisionValue1;

        if (decisionValue1 == 4)
        {
            int x = decisionValue2;
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need braces to change the scope.
Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894119/variables-scope-in-a-switch-case

Comment: @ChrisThompson Not necessarily. Scopes can be changed without braces (e.g. one line if statements).

Comment: They're not in disjoint scopes.  The scope of the first x is the entire case statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java "Duplicate local variable" - is the error thrown in Java or Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441995/java-duplicate-local-variable-is-the-error-thrown-in-java-or-eclipse)

Comment: Hint:  Surround the "body" of `case 1` with `{}`.

Comment: Hey guys. I just edited my original question - SAME issue but without a switch statement! Please see edit section.

Comment: @Phoeniyx The problem is if the compiler looks at the line: `System.out.println(x);`. How does it know which `x` to print?

Comment: You're right that it's exactly the same -- you removed the switch but kept the problem.

Comment: @cabelicar123 In C++, the "x" reference would pickup the "closest" matching "x" - and there would be NO error. In this case, the "x" inside the if statement. Coming from the C++ world, I thought Java worked the same! But thank you all for pointing out that Java acts differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a `switch` statement does not have to `break` and the flow of execution can continue into the next case they are not in different scopes. The fact that the second `x` is in an `if` statement does not change this as the `if` is still in the `switch` statement.

When you add the second `x` you are equivalently doing this:

```
+-------+
|   x   |
| +---+ |
| | x | |
| +---+ |
+-------+
```

As you can see there are two `x`s within the same box (not allowed).

Adding curly braces around the first declaration of `x`:

```
case 1:
{
    int x = decisionValue1;
    System.out.println(x);
    break;
}
```

Will cause a picture like this:

```
+-------+
| +---+ |
| | x | |
| +---+ |
| +---+ |
| | x | |
| +---+ |
+-------+
```

That is allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I can appreciate that the compiler may not be "smart" enough to recognize that there is an unconditional break statement at the end - I can live with that. But, the "if" statement DOES create a new local scope.. Doesn't it? Or is it just something I have to live with?..

Comment: @Phoeniyx Yes, but it's nested within the switch's scope, which declares `int x`.

Comment: @Phoeniyx - Java does not allow multiple variables by the same name in the same local scope.

Comment: Thanks guys. Just to clarify, a sub-scope does NOT create a "new scope" within Java - such that references within sub-scope (inner square) refers to only the innermost declaration? I guess that is what your example is saying. This is NOT the case in C++. Surprising.. I also edited my original question with a "non-switch" example. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to two things:

1. Scopes are nested
2. Everything in a `switch` is in one scope -- different cases don't matter.

So, the switch declares an `int x` within the `case 1` section. Then, in the `case 2` section, your `if` block declares a nested scope that also tries to declare `int x`, and that's what the compiler doesn't allow.

One solution would be to put an "anonymous block" in the `case 1` section. You can put a block anywhere that you can put a statement, and it creates its own scope:

```
case 1:
{ // anonymous scope
    int x = ...
}
```

That way, the outermost scope in the `switch` doesn't declare `int x`, and you're fine.

As a fun fact, this is exactly what's happening with your `if` statement! The thing that has to follow an `if(condition)` is just a single statement; most of the time, that statement is a block, but in that regard this block-as-statement is no different than any one that's just "randomly" placed in your code.

Comment: Thanks yshavit (and everyone else above as well). I guess this is another way that Java differs from C++. In C++, sub-scopes would allow you to use the same name as of a variable in the parent-scope. Guess this is not allowed in Java. What bothered me most was not the switch statement, but the error in relation to the nested "if" statement. I also edited my original question with a non-switch example. In any case, I will try your approach.